# What command can I use instead of withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: '', gitToolName: '')]) in pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

The version of jenkins is 2.252 and the version of the jenkins git plugin is 4.3.

The contents of my pipeline are shown below:

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'slave3' }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'GITCHOICE', choices: ['tag', 'build'], description: 'Select TAG or BUILD')
    }

    stages {

        stage('Preparation') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'printenv'
                    cleanWs()
                    def CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH = "${params.CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH}"
                    if (CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH != 'master') {
                        CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH = "${params.CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH}"
                    }
                    sh "repo init -b ${CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH} -u ssh://git@192.168.0.3/${CUSTOM_REPO_PROJECT}"
                    sh "repo sync" 
            }
        }

        stage('tag') {
            when { expression { params.GITCHOICE == 'tag' } }
            steps {
                script {
                    def microservices = ['goodwx', 'proxy', 'audit']
                    for (int i = 0; i < microservices.size(); ++i) {
                        sh "cd $WORKSPACE/${microservices[i]} && git tag ${TAG_VERSION} && git push manifests ${TAG_VERSION}"
                    }
                    withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: '1234a567-4321-1a23-ace4-1a2a8e678a2b', gitToolName: 'git-tool')]) {
                    sh "cd $WORKSPACE/.repo/manifests/ && sed -i 's#deploy#refs/tags/${TAG_VERSION}#g' default.xml && git add default.xml && git commit -m 'modify default.xml to add tag' && git push origin && git tag ${TAG_VERSION} && git push origin ${TAG_VERSION}"
            }
            }
        }
}
```

I build this pipeline, it report error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'gitUsernamePassword' found among steps [VersionNumber, acceptGitLabMR, addBadge, addErrorBadge, addGitLabMRComment, addHtmlBadge, addInfoBadge, addShortText, addWarningBadge, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, createSummary, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerNode, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, gitChangelog, gitlabBuilds, gitlabCommitStatus, httpRequest, input, isUnix, jiraComment, jiraIssueSelector, jiraSearch, junit, library, libraryResource, load, lock, mail, milestone, node, parallel, powershell, properties, publishHTML, pwd, pwsh, readFile, readTrusted, release, removeBadges, removeHtmlBadges, removeSummaries, resolveScm, retry, script, setGerritReview, sh, sleep, springConfig, sshCommand, sshGet, sshPut, sshRemove, sshScript, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstable, unstash, updateGitlabCommitStatus, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitForQualityGate, waitUntil, warnError, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, withMaven, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [absolute, all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, artifactsPublisher, attach, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, bitbucket, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildDiscarders, buildingTag, bzt, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeAbandoned, changeMerged, changeRequest, changeRestored, changelog, changeset, checkboxParameter, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, cifsPublisher, cleanWs, clock, command, commentAdded, commentAddedContains, concordionPublisher, configFile, configFileProvider, credentials, cron, crumb, cssText, cssUrl, culprits, default, defaultFolderConfiguration, defaultView, demand, dependenciesFingerprintPublisher, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downstream, draftPublished, dumb, durabilityHint, envVars, envVarsFilter, environment, equals, executor, expression, faviconUrl, file, fileParam, filePath, findbugsPublisher, fingerprint, fingerprints, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, gerrit, git, gitBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchHeadAuthority, gitHubForkDiscovery, gitHubTagDiscovery, gitHubTrustContributors, gitHubTrustEveryone, gitHubTrustNobody, gitHubTrustPermissions, gitLabConnection, gitParameter, gitTagDiscovery, github, githubPush, gitlab, globalConfigFiles, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, invokeCommand, invokerPublisher, isRestartedRun, jacocoPublisher, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jgivenPublisher, jnlp, jobBuildDiscarder, jobName, jsUrl, junitPublisher, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, listGitBranches, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, mailer, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenLinkerPublisher, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, newContainerPerStage, node, nodeProperties, nodejs, nodejsci, nonInheriting, none, not, openTasksPublisher, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parallelsAlwaysFailFast, parameters, password, patchsetCreated, pattern, perfReport, performanceReport, performanceTest, permanent, pipeline-model, pipeline-model-docker, pipelineGraphPublisher, pipelineMaven, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, previous, privateStateChanged, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, pruneTags, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rateLimitBuilds, recipients, refUpdated, relative, requestor, resourceRoot, retainOnlyVariables, run, runParam, sSHLauncher, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApproval, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, sendFile, shell, simple-theme-plugin, simpleBuildDiscarder, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, snapshotDependencies, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, spotbugsPublisher, ssh, sshPublicKey, sshPublisher, sshPublisherDesc, sshTransfer, sshUserPrivateKey, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, tag, testCase, text, textParam, timestamper, timestamperConfig, timezone, tmpSpace, toolLocation, topicChanged, triggeredBy, unsecured, upstream, upstreamDevelopers, userSeed, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, websocketin, winRMClient, wipStateChanged, withAnt, withSonarQubeEnv, withVault, workspace, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, manager, params, pipeline, scm]
```

After I google, I find:

**You can use gitUsernamePassword to automatically authenticate yourself when executing git commands, but this requires a version of the git plugin for jenkins that is 4.8.1 or higher.**

But my jenkins git plugin is 4.3.

My question is

What command can I use instead of this line in pipeline

```
withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: '1234a567-4321-1a23-ace4-1a2a8e678a2b', gitToolName: ' git-tool')])
```

for git authentication?

Comment: Is installing the plugin not an option?